# How can I get the input impedance of this multistage amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, input-impedance

I was trying to figure out the input impedance of this multistage amplifier.
[image]

The input impedance of the other stages can be simplified to \$R_{i2}\$.
[image]

I tried to replace T1 with the hirbid model but I don't really know what to do next.

[image]

Comment: Well, if you consider \$T_4\$ gate of infinite input impedance then you have to replace each transistor \$T_1\$ to \$T_3\$ by its hybrid-\$\pi\$ model and determine the input impedance by installing a test generator \$I_T\$ biasing the input and developing a voltage \$V_T\$ across its terminals. The input impedance will be \$Z_{in}(s)=\frac{V_T(s)}{I_T(s)}\$. I would capture this equivalent circuit in SPICE and progress step by step.

Comment: As @Verbal says, drop T4 as infinite. You can ignore it. Just look at T3. Tell me what you see as its AC impedance. Note that the emitter is "shorted" by C2. What does this say about what's reflected back to the base as its impedance seen from the base? Do you think that ro for T3 or its collector resistor matter in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspection, \$R_{i2} = (\beta +1)*(R_2 + r_{e2})\$, and we also see that \$T_1\$ is working as a diode connected BJT's. Thus, the resistance seen from the \$T_1\$ collector is \$R_3||(r_{e1} + R_1)\$
So, the overall input resistance will be equal to:

\$R_i = R_3\:||\:(r_{e1} + R_1)\:||\:[(\beta +1)(R_2 + r_{e2})]\$

Where:

\$ \large r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E} \approx \frac{26mV}{I_E} \approx \frac{1}{g_m} = \frac{h_{ie}}{h_{fe} +1} \$

\$\beta \approx h_{fe}\$

Thus, the dominant factor will be \$R_3||R_1\$ or even \$R_1\$

This is what I get by inspection.

Comment: I just figured out the expression just minutes before you answered, we got to the same equation. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.